# Use built-in Octicons in editor/title menu for vscode extension command contribution point

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to use Octitons that [ship with](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) vscode without embedding it into my extension?

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "my.extraordinary.command",
        "title": "My command",
        "icon":{
          "dark": "<what should go here?>",
          "light": "<what should go here?>"
        }  
      },
    ],
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [
        {
          "command": "my.extraordinary.command",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: It looks like you need to include the icon `svg` files into your extension. Have a look at the build in git extension here [Github Vscode Git extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/git/resources/icons)